# "Error: Couldn't find that app. › › Error ID: not_found." when running heroku commands in console

Tags: django, heroku

Heroku sees my app in the list of apps, but I can't access it with any commands. I constantly getting the error "Couldn't find that app".  I tried all these:

[image]

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate --app app-generator
heroku run python manage.py migrate
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser --app app-generator
```

Although when I try to run commands for 'heroku apps' in my console, says I have one app called my-api. I followed other similar questions and tried the  git remote  commands beforehand but still failed. Example:

```
heroku apps
heroku git:remote -app app-generator
```

Comment: I believe the Heroku CLI app flags are `-a` or `--app`, try one of those instead

Comment: Still didn't work..

Comment: Do you actually own the app named `app-generator`, or did you copy that from a tutorial somewhere? If that is another user's app you won't be allowed to interact with it in this way. Imagine the security implications if you could read back-end logs of arbitrary apps on Heroku.

Answer (score -1):

If it's another user's heroku project. Then you need to use "... -a name" where `name` should be name of the `team`, not the name of the app. Login to heroku and find the team name from the dropdown.And run commands again.

Comment: "you need to use "... -a name" where `name` should be name of the team, not the name of the app"—this doesn't make any sense. Why would you provide the name of a team as an argument to the `-a` flag, which is short for `--app`? And how would Heroku know _which_ of the team's apps you are trying to interact with? With shared apps you would still provide the app name, not the team name. But you need to have been granted access to the app in question.